# Replace strings with double quotes in a XML file

Tags: regex, perl, sed, awk, pattern-matching

I have a huge XML file with longer lines (5000-10000 characters per line) with following text:

```
Pattern="abc"
```

and I want to replace it with

```
Pattern="def"
```

As the line sizes are huge, I have no choice but to use awk. Please suggest how this can be achieved. I tried with the below but it is not working:

```
CMD="{sub(\"Pattern=\"abc\"\",\"Pattern=\"def\"\"); print}"
echo "$CMD"
awk "$CMD" "Some File Name.xml"
```

Any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: Never try to put an awk script in a variable and then pass it to awk, it's always 100% the wrong approach.

Comment: awk "{sub(\"Pattern=\"abc\"\",\"Pattern=\"def\"\"); print}" "Some File Name.xml" did not work!

Comment: Good then your awk is not broken.

Answer (score 2):

I don't understand why you said "As the line sizes are huge, I have no choice but to use awk". AFAIK sed is no more limited on line length than awk is and since this is a simple substitution on a single line, sed is the better choice of tool:

```
$ cat file
Pattern="abc"
$ sed -r 's/(Pattern=")[^"]+/\1def/' file
Pattern="def"
```

If the pattern occurs multiple times on the line, add a "g" to the end of the line.

Since you mention in your comment being stuck with a sed that can't handle long lines, let's assume you can't install GNU tools so you'll need a non-GNU awk solution like this:

```
$ awk '{sub(/Pattern="[^"]+/,"Pattern=\"def")}1' file
Pattern="def"
```

If you LITERALLY mean you only want to replace `Pattern="abc"` then just do:

```
$ awk '{sub(/Pattern="abc"/,"Pattern=\"def\"")}1' file
Pattern="def"
```

Comment: Thanks for reply. I am working legacy unix platform (not linux), where sed is not able to manipulate lines greater than certain size. I know sed is the easiest. But, it is skipping large lines in result. So, I started looking for awk way.

Comment: I added an awk solution. If you're on Solaris, do NOT use /bin/awk as that's old, broken, awk - use /usr/xpg4/bin/awk or nawk instead.

Comment: Then you won't have that Solaris problem I mentioned.

Comment: Here is my file content (line2 is very long).

    $ cat -n t1.xml
         1  Value="abc"
         2  some text Pattern="abc" some text
         3  Type="0"
         4  Pattern="/abc/xyz"

Comment: Trial-1:
    Using gsub("find","replace")

    $ /usr/bin/nawk "{gsub(\"Pattern=\"abc\"\",\"Pattern=\"def\"\"); print}" t1.xml
    Value="abc"
    some text Pattern="abc" some text
    Type="0"
    Pattern="/abc/xyz"

Comment: Trial-2:
    Using gsub(/find/,"replace")

    $ /usr/bin/nawk "{gsub(/Pattern=\"abc\"/,\"Pattern=\"def\"\"); print}" t1.xml
    Value="abc"
    some text Pattern= some text
    Type="0"
    Pattern="/abc/xyz"
    $

None of them works!

Comment: $ awk '{sub(/Pattern="[^"]+"/,"Pattern=\"def")}1' t1.xml
    Value="abc"
    some text Pattern="def some text
    Type="0"
    Pattern="def

This works, but replaces all occurances of
    Pattern="

Comment: You can't put formatted multi-line text in a comment. Update your posted question if you have some code and input/output or error messages to show us. It looks like none of the solutions you attempted are the solution I proposed - copy/paste the script I posted, don't try to re-type it yourself as you're changing it.

Answer (score 2):

one suggestion with [awk](/questions/tagged/awk)

```
BEGIN {FS="\""; OFS=""}
/Pattern="abc"/{$2="\"def\""}1
```

Answer (score 0):

If You have [bash](/questions/tagged/bash) you can try this:

Create file with long lines (>10_000 chars):

```
for((i=0;i<2500;++i));{ s="x$s";}
l="${s}Pattern=\"abc\"$s"
for i in {1..5}; { echo "$l$l";} >infile
```

The script:

```
while read x; do echo "${x//Pattern=\"abc\"/Pattern=\"def\"}";done <infile
```

This replaces all occurrences of `Pattern="abc"` to `Pattern="def"` in each line.